# Python function to reduce numbers to single digit

Tags: function, python-2.7, math, while-loop

So the way this function reduces the value down to a single digit is to continuously add the digits of a value together in a loop until it is a value of 9 or less. The issue comes in when the two digits added together equate to 10 which should then be further reduced by adding 1 + 0 for a value of 1.

```
def rts(value):
   VALUE_STR = str(value)
   ANSWER = "0"
   while value > 9:
      value = int("0")
      for ch in VALUE_STR:
         ch = int(ch)
         value += ch
      ANSWER = str(value)
   return ANSWER
```

I can't really show output per-say but when I have it print out it will get stuck in an endless loop anytime it is passed a numeric value that when added equals 10.

**EXAMPLE 1:** 
91 
9 + 1 = 10 
commence endless loop

**EXAMPLE 2:**
64
6 + 4 = 10 
commence endless loop

The way it works with other numbers

**EXAMPLE 1:** 
97 
9 + 7 = 16 
16
6 + 1 = 7 
ANSWER = 7

**EXAMPLE 2:** 
45
4 + 5 = 9
ANSWER = 9

Here is the fixed code for anyone needing similar functionality.

```
def rts(value):
   VALUE_STR = str(value)
   ANSWER = "0"
   while value > 9:
      value = int("0")
      for ch in VALUE_STR:
         ch = int(ch)
         value += ch
      ANSWER = str(value)
      VALUE_STR = str(value)

   return ANSWER
```

Comment: You're not updating `VALUE_STR` inside the loop (note that variables should be `lowercase_with_underscores`), so any input that requires more than one pass through the loop will get stuck - have a look using e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Why are you doing this with strings, of all things? Not even addressing efficiency, this is a valid thing to try just mathematically -- and the code would be clearer. What is `x / 10`? What is `x % 10`? In what case would you face > 9 results from addition and test for this?

Comment: I do it to drop any number to a single whole digit dividing by 10 will not always be a whole number. Plus for what the number is used for later in the program simplicity isn't exactly the goal. I don't understand your last question "In what case would you face > 9 results from addition and test for this?". If you are asking with my method when could it be > 9 I gave examples for this. As for your method thats as simple as 117 / 10 = 11.3 thus would need to be divided again by 10 which would be 1.17 rounded down to 1. My method would be finished in one iteration of 1+1+7 = 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
for ch in VALUE_STR:
```

you feed back the original string in every run of the loop. So, any execution that takes more than one iteration would create an endless loop.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was all I had to do was add `VALUE_STR = str(value)` after the `VALUE_STR = str(value)` line... Thanks for catching that. Wow I feel dumb lol.

Answer (score 2):

This function is doing the same in a different way. It iterates through digits in a number and sums them. Then checks if the result is single-digit. If not, it recursively call itself.

```
def rts(input_number):
    input_number = str(input_number)
    value = 0

    for x in input_number:
        value += int(x)

    if (value > 9):
        return rts(value)
    else:
        return value
```

Comment: So what have you changed, and *why*? Also, note that you don't comply with the style guide.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wrote a different function with a same goal. It sums all digits with recursion until only one digit is remaining. What is wrong with style guide? maybe you can suggest an edit and I will accept it.

Comment: See [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - compound statements are discouraged. It's also helpful to say why and how your answer solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  sorry, my bad. I'm going to repair it in a minute.

Comment: Much better, although it still doesn't actually explain the problem with the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was dynamic but it gives expected output:

```
nlist = input("Enter the number: ")
val = 0
num = 0
for n in nlist:
    val = val + int(n)
for i in str(val):
    num += int(i)
print("Reduce number by sum is: ", num)
```

OUTPUT :

Enter the number: 46

4 + 6 = 10

1 + 0 = 1

Reduce number by sum is : 1

Answer (score 0):

reduce as required: D works well to use o

```
def digit_root(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1
```